# Related to a complex architechture to scrape in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I want to extract the first two features from costs, characteristics, and domestic equipment fields but due to complex tagging.

[This](https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/5c9ee425b6c6c87a0253fae1) is the website.

PS: it's in German so please convert it to English.

For extraction of features from cost I am using : `soup.find('div,{class:at-accordion-content})`, then I am again using `.find()` but I am getting `None`.

I have to extract from 1.) cost - Purchase price and operating cost
                       2.)characteristics- surface area, living space. 
similarly other.

Can someone please provide me the code, how to extract from this website?

Comment: Are you using the requests module to get the page content for the BS4 parser? If so, then you will likely need to switch to browser automation such as Selenium, as the page appears to use asynchronous scripting that means the full content won't load on a simple http request. It would help to see the code for what you've tried so far, see this link: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could make the same request the page does to return results, i.e. use the same API, and parse the json response.

`r['hits']` has all the results, in this case 1. You could loop the items in this if more than one result (you'd lose the index e.g. `item['priceInformation']['primaryPrice']`

```
import requests

headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*'}
r = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.at/api/psa/is24/properties/search?accountCwid=012.0012000001E83sA&areaNumberOfRoomsFrom=4&areaPrimaryAreaFrom=120&from=0&localizationGeoHierarchy=003006018&matchSubProperties=true&priceInformationHasPriceOnRequest=false&priceInformationPrimaryPriceTo=552000&size=5&typeEstateType=HOUSE&typeTransferType=BUY&typeUseType=RESIDENTIAL', headers = headers).json()

purchase_price = r['hits'][0]['priceInformation']['primaryPrice']
operating_cost = r['hits'][0]['priceInformation']['costs']['operationalCosts']['total']
surface = r['hits'][0]['area']['totalArea']
living_space = r['hits'][0]['area']['livingArea']
room = r['hits'][0]['area']['numberOfRooms']
bathroom = r['hits'][0]['area']['numberOfBathrooms']
print(purchase_price, operating_cost, surface, living_space, room, bathroom )
```

Comment: Any questions please let me know.

Comment: Hi @QHarr.Thanks a lot for the reply. But how did you transform the URL in requests.get(), Can you please explain? 

I have to extract the same information for other houses and I am not able to write the url the way you have written here.

Comment: Like the next link is: https://www.immobilienscout24.at/expose/5c45bb067416f91444ff3939

how to write requests.get() for this url?

Comment: I used the network tab to find the actual query the page uses to retrieve content. I think you modify the query string to retrieve other info.  If you provide another url you want data for I can have a look.

Comment: the next link is: immobilienscout24.at/expose/5c45bb067416f91444ff3939   .Can I get this modified query string in python by some commands? Because I am using for loops and have many of these houses link to extract data from.